# jQuery code disabling other jQuery code

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

When I add a regular strip of javascript code to my `$(document).ready(function () {})`, jQuery features such as accordion and tabs stop working. How can this be fixed? (other jQuery features such as dialog and drag still work though)

JAVASCRIPT

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $(function () {   
      $("#accord").accordion()
  });    

  $(function (){
      $("#tabs").tabs();
  }); 

  /*This strip is causing the above functions to not work*/
  document.getElementById("myID").innerHTML = "text";
})
```

Comment: So what errors are thrown? Also no need to wrap things with `$(function()` inside `$(document).ready`. They are exactly the same thing. Create a demo that replicates your problem

Comment: Do you have the same problem if you use `$("#myID").html("text");`?

Comment: Are the accordion and tab DIVs inside the `myID` DIV?

Comment: $("#myID").html("text"); solves the problem thanks!